# Unity and Firebase are looking for google-services.json with the wrong path and a backslash

Tags: c#, json, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm using Firebase with Unity for the first time, and all the references I can find seem pretty straightforward, but it seems something in the code somewhere is broken and I don't know how to even find it, let alone fix it. The error I'm receiving is this:

```
Unable to load Firebase app options
([C:/Users/Morgan/Cards/Assets/StreamingAssets\google-services-desktop.json,
C:/Users/Morgan/Cards/Assets/StreamingAssets\google-services.json] are missing or malformed)
```

I have a `google-services.json` file, and I've been told that Firebase will look for that and make the `google-services-desktop.json` file for me, but I have no way of putting my file at the location it's looking for it because that's not a location that can possibly exist. I think I wouldn't be having this problem if there was even one character of difference there (I can put it in a "StreamingAssets" folder, and I tried that but it didn't work). Can anyone give me pointers on where/how to fix the path?

(Note: I'm finding a lot of questions where people are having trouble with Firebase, but none where they have this specific problem. It seems like it would be a common problem, but I've really been looking.)

Comment: The service doesn't have access to your local files in /Users/Morgan.  You need to put files in a location where the service has access like a Network drive that allows all users to access the file.  A service normally runs with System credentials as default which has very limited access to the resource on the machine like users accounts.  This is intentional to limit a back door for hackers to access the machine.